¿Cómo puedo generar una consulta que discrimine resultados?
Ante todo, gracias por leer. Estoy tratando de hacer algo que creo que es sencillo, pero no sé si por agotamiento no puedo ver:
Tengo una tabla con nombres, apellidos y fechas. Intento que, si para una fecha ese nombre no está, lo genere a partir del resto de fechas.
Parto de dos consultas:
$consultanombres = "SELECT DISTINCT nombre, apellido1, apellido2 
    FROM minerva.parte_digital";
$rescn = mysqli_query($conn, $consultanombres);

$consultafechas = "SELECT DISTINCT fecha 
    FROM minerva.parte_digital";
$rescf = mysqli_query($conn, $consultafechas);

Con ambas consultas obtengo los resultados que necesito, pero trato de hacer un foreach/while con una de las dos y dentro de esta otro bucle. De manera, que con un INSERT IGNORE, si no existe la cree.
En fin, a ver si alguien me ilumina.
Un saludo!

Yo no entendí  Por qué tienes dos consultas? Con una query usando JOIN puedes hacer lo mismo. Y con una condicional donde evalúes que si no hay resultados haga el insert. Yo lo veo super simple, pero no se si eso es lo que quieres. Explica las cosas sin tecnicismos, así a lo calle a ver que le hacemos

Creo que es justo lo que dices. Estoy mirando la documentación de JOIN, pero si me pones un ejemplo, te lo agradezco.

Acá hice un ejemplo de JOINs, por lo demás hasta el lunes te puedo ayudar si no has podido resolver. Pero insisto, decir "Creo que es justo lo que dices" no me sirve de nada. Explica ombe, si no tengo una petición exacta (en mi caso) yo no actúo. Nos leemos el lunes

Yo no entendí el problema, te recomiendo agregar un ejemplo de entrada y salida esperada
